# Facebook App permissions. JSP and RestFB

Tags: jsp, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, restfb

I am making a simple Facebook app for a small research experiment. I am using restFB for getting a Facebook group members information. I am specifically interested in getting the "About" information and getBio() of group members. I am not a programmer. So please bear with my lack of information, I really need a way out as I can not find enough information on web.

I have the following working code:

```
 String AccessTokenJS = request.getParameter("accTokenName");
 // I get the token accTokenName using the JavaScript Facebook Login code

 out.println("<BR>Retreived Token: " + AccessTokenJS);

 String appId="***************";
 String appSecret="****************************";
 FacebookClient facebookClient = new DefaultFacebookClient(AccessTokenJS, appSecret);

 Group group1 = facebookClient.fetchObject("****************",Group.class);
 out.println("<BR><BR>The Group Name is : " + group1.getName() );

 Connection<User> gmem = facebookClient.fetchConnection("***************/members", User.class);
 out.println("<BR>Total Group Members: " + gmem.getData().size());


 for (User u : gmem.getData())
 {  
       out.println("<BR> :"+u.getName());
       out.println("<BR> :"+u.getLastName());
       out.println("<BR> :"+u.getBio());
 }
```

The code is working fine and prints .getName()

**but**

getLastName() and **getBio()** print **Null** from the  biographical information. I am also a member of the group and I biographical information in my profile.

My problem will be solved if I could somehow get this getLastName() and **getBio()** print actual values.

I think the issue may because the Token generated using the JavaScript authentication doesn't have the permissions to access more information.

*** Can someone please guide me about how can I go further from here?

*** Do I have to visit app page as developer and actually select the permissions for this?

and after that, Do all the members of this group have to install this app in the Facebook before my this code can start printing the information using **getBio()** .

I will really appreciate some one could show me specific steps that I should follow to get the  biographical information printed about the members of the group.

Thank you very much.

Syed

Answer (score 0):

You use the `<group-id>/members` endpoint to fetch a list of users. That's the right way, but Facebook provides only a minimal set of information in that list. So you get only the name and the id.

You should in a second step fetch the information for every `<user-id>`. There you'll find the `lastname`. I'm not sure how the bio information is handled. It's possible the user have to allow you to see this information.